# Storing images in BerkeleyDB

Tags: database, perl, image, berkeley-db, key-value

I use BerkeleyDB in Perl with DB_File.

1. How to store images (small size) as values?
2. Is BerkeleyDB a right choice for storing images within database? as unlike some other database systems, Berkeley DB offers no special support for binary large objects (BLOBs).
3. Storing images in mysql is questionable as implementing changes to a large database is harder; but is it the case for a key/value database like Berkeley.DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to store images (small size) as values?

Exactly as documented, read file, say using [File::Slurp::read_file](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aSlurp), taking care to `binmode`, and store the value in the hash.

> Is BerkeleyDB a right choice for storing images within database? as unlike some other database systems, Berkeley DB offers no special support for binary large objects (BLOBs).

BerkeleyDB, not being a relational database, doesn't have field types with limitations, so you can store anything (with the usual caveats)

> Storing images in MySQL is questionable as implementing changes to a large database is harder; but is it the case for a key/value database like Berkeley.DB?

Yes, storing binary data is questionable, because the filesystem is so good at doing exactly that, but people do it all the time without too much trouble — remember to backup your data regularly.

Comment: @shrinkly: which document you are referring to?

Comment: [DB_File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DB_File), [BerkeleyDB](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?BerkeleyDB), [BerkeleyDB FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/db-faq-095848.html), [db_verify](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/db_verify.html) ...